# Java for loop to print t's and f's in lines of 3

Tags: for-loop, char

Ok so I was wondering if there was a way to print out 3 char variables that will either equal 't' or 'f' 8 times with each possible combination.  I know that I can easily hard code it in there but I was curious to if you could do it with a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
    if(i&1)
        System.out.print("t");
    else
       System.out.print("f");

    if(i&2)
        System.out.print("t");
    else
       System.out.print("f");

    if(i&4)
        System.out.print("t");
    else
       System.out.print("f");

    System.out.println("");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Char [] c={`t`,`f`};
     For(char CH: c){
          For(char c1: c){
              For(char c2: c){
                 System.out.println(CH+""+c1+c2);.   }}}
```